# Version control a file from directory only when I ask, rather than initial full commit for entire directory?

Tags: git, svn, version-control, github

Could I put a certain file in some VCS like git/subversion/etc only "when" I am  modifying it. So first I put the unmodified version & then the modified version. The desire is to put the file in VCS only when I want, rather than doing initial full directory commits.. Is this possible ?

I want to version some of the configuration files that I modify on my ubuntu server, but I wish not to do an initial full directory commit, rather i'm looking if it is possible to a add file to VCS just before I am modifying the file.. how could i achieve this ?

Comment: Well, you add the file, then commit it. Where's the problem?

Comment: is it possible to add a each of the file to VCS just before i' m modifying them ? Until now I just used a fixed directory from where all files were under VCS..

Comment: so previously it was like I added the directory & everything under it was commiited as an initial commit.. & now I just want to avoid storing the default state of files.. I would manualy tell for each of the file when to commit that file to VCS. how could I do that ?

Comment: You're not forced to add every file in a directory to the VCS. I wouldn't say that it's a good idea to do so (you want to be able to clone your repo elsewhere and get all you neeed), but it's perfectly doable. Just add files instead of the whole directory: `git add myFile; git commit`

Comment: thanks.. that makes sense..why don't you post as an answer ? Could you also clarify, If I dynamically add files to my VCS at different points of times, wont my repo be clonable to some other location ?(did your last comment meant to imply this ?) Actually I would  save default state just prior to committing my changes.. & then do a next commmit of  changed version.. but not an initial commit for everthing as that is that's default configuration  files for ubunutu & packages which i would get when i reinstall

Comment: No. It will be clonable. But it will only contain the files you aded and committed. So you'll end up with only a few of the files you actually need. There's no reason not to version all the files you need.

Comment: thanks i think this i what I would want for my configuration backup so that I could fast reinstall OS with my custom configuration for packages.

Comment: If your goal is to save versioned system configuration in git, you may like [etckeeper](https://github.com/joeyh/etckeeper).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a custom script to deal with keeping the default state of files before editing them &  the current state. [Only these two version of each modified file]. The diff of them(default state & current state) could be used to keep track of all the total changes I made. This would not keep the changes version by version. However this could be used to calculate all total customization I made to files on my system & hence use for later regeneration on another system as well.
Note that this would not provide a backup, but just additional data beside other backup for easily rebuilding new system with my configurations.

Here's the script. (I would execute it prior to making any changes to any configuration file):

```
#!/bin/bash   

# This is script to remember default & current state of manually edited configuration files.. from anywhere on system..     
# the diffs between current & default may be used to regenerate configurations on another machine.
# Only when used for first time on  a file, it is stored in default state directory otherwise stored in current state directory..

# $1 - 1st passed parameter... this should be subject file  

DEFAULT_STATE_DIR="/root/state-default/" 
CURRENT_STATE_DIR="/root/state-current/" 

FILE=$1

# create the DEFAULT_STATE_DIR & CURRENT_STATE_DIR directories if they dont yet exist.. 
if [ ! -d "$DEFAULT_STATE_DIR" ]; then  
  mkdir $DEFAULT_STATE_DIR
fi
if [ ! -d "$CURRENT_STATE_DIR" ]; then  
  mkdir $CURRENT_STATE_DIR
fi

# fail incase user did not provided full file path(starting from /) in parameter
if  [[ $FILE==/* ]]; then   
    echo "Proceeding.."
else
    echo "Specify full File path starting with /"
    echo "Will stop now."
    exit 0
fi

# convert all '/' in the file path to '-', so the name used contains hint about path as well
FILENAME_TO_USE=$(echo "$FILE" | sed 's;/;-;g')     



if [ -f $DEFAULT_STATE_DIR/$FILENAME_TO_USE ]; # if default state is already stored..then store this as current state..
then
   echo "Initial state for File $FILE already stored. Storing as current modified state.."
   cp $FILE $CURRENT_STATE_DIR/$FILENAME_TO_USE
   echo "Modified."
else
   echo "Initial state for File $FILE didn't existed. Storing the current state as initial state of this file.."
   cp $FILE $DEFAULT_STATE_DIR/$FILENAME_TO_USE
   echo "Added."
fi
```